# Getting the value of UISwitch in a %i form

Tags: ios, objective-c

I got a tedious little problem.

I need to pass on the value that is set by a UISwitch, so since it is a boolean I was thinking it would return an integer, hence the %i in my code below.

I have looked and a lot of UISwitched have their value displayed like so:

```
if(nameOfSwitch.isOn)
{
  NSLog(@"The switch is on");
}
else
{
  NSLog(@"The switch is off");
}
```

I need the Boolean value, since I need to this:

```
NSString *value = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Value of Switch %i" nameOfSwitch.on];
```

This however always seem to return that is switched on - so what is the right way to do it??

**I need the equivalent of UITextField.text for the UISwitch**

Comment: try `[[NSNumber numberWithBOOL:switch.on] intValue];` smgt like that

Comment: Using `%i` (or `%d`) is fine for a `BOOL` value. You should see `0` for `NO` and `1` for `YES`. What are you getting?

Comment: I am just getting 1, but once I tested it with the switch switched off, it was still passing on a 1 instead of a 0

Comment: Use the debugger and verify the state of switch.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can try

```
NSString *value = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Value of Switch: %i",nameOfSwitch.isOn];
```

or

```
NSString *value = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Value of Switch: %@",nameOfSwitch.isOn?@"YES":@"NO"];
```

By the way it should be

```
if(nameOfSwitch.isOn)
{
  NSLog(@"The switch is on");
}
else
{
  NSLog(@"The switch is off");
}
```

Edit: If you are seeing this switch as ON, and you are not getting the 1 you wanted, then your problem might be that you are calling the wrong switch name or that it is not the same instance (you have one in the Interface Builder and you init one by code as well)

Comment: Your second line worked:-) i guess it needed a string as a placeholder to display.

Comment: the first line shows the value of a switch as an integer, the second displays the text that I wrote there depending on the value of the switch. Btw try to use isON when you want to get the value since that is the correct getter.